# Can gated recurrent units be deployed on ARM cortex a53?

Tags: machine-learning, arm, lstm, cortex-a

I have a task of performing regression learning on a target board (ARM Cortex A53 processor).

I have completed the tasks of data and feature extraction.

Now, i am analyzing the performances of different learning algorithms (GRUs and LSTM) in tensorflow.

However, my concern is that not all models has the software supports to be deployed on the target board. Based on my research i found the below picture depicting ways of doing this.

[image: ML4ARM]

Out of the software libraries, i found out that only ARM NN on top of ARM compute library (ACL) is the way to go.

Although ACL has the function defnitions needed for the basic defnition of LSTM. In its description, ACL specifies that it supports only SVM (Binary Classification) and CNN models.

Has anyone successfully deployed GRU/LSTM/Random Forest models on a "ARM-Cortex A" CPU?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got a satisfiable answer to my question - https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/issues/331. I will update this post once i confirm the solution